# Do we have a borderless theme for GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome, themes

Do we have any Aqua like borderless themes for GNOME 3 ??

When I say Aqua like i don't mean the whole traffic light buttons and stuff like Mac4Linux, rather a theme with 0px borders and larger window shadows.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the new Ubuntu Ambiance and Radiance themes are just like that.

[image]
Epiphany 3.0

[image]
Gwibber 3.1.5

**Note:**
All the windows are borderless, but I have not captured the shadows (yet). I will update my answer with better screen-shots a bit later. Also, it is possible that we will get anti-aliased edges and smooth shadows in Compiz.

Comment: Roland ... some nice piccies would complete this answer very nicely :)

Comment: @fossfreedom: true. I'll post some soon.